# Organisation of folders on NEXTGIS

Tags: qgis-2.18, nextgis

I am trying to set up a folder called 'November' on NEXTGIS such that I can add multiple web maps into subfolders called 1,2,3,etc over time. I want to give a web address to a coworker for the folder 'November' which will include links to all subfolders. They can monitor this page to see updated maps throughout November.[image]

The resultant web page looks like this:
[image]

Is there a cleaner way of setting up a process such as this?

Comment: it's not clean to me: a) do you need a way to create folders with same structure i.e. December, January ... or b) do you need a way to setup user permissions for folders and subfolders?

Comment: I want to send a link to a (non-technical) coworker such that that link will allow him to get to links to all subfolders/webmaps. Idiot proof for a non-technical person.

Comment: and giving your collegue a link to November folder won't work?

Comment: You end up with the very complex window (see image) with a lot of edit/delete buttons, new resources, extras, etc. This seems unnecessarily (visually) confusing for a non technical person. But this is the only option available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a interface for an established system. If you need a different interface for a non-technical person, you can:

1. simply put up a small web page with all links somewhere on your hosting
2. create a folder/group with web-maps only (so he/she needs just to learn how open a webmap)
3. program completely new frontend (REST API [is available](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngweb_dev/doc/developer/toc.html))

**Disclosure**: I am a developer at NextGIS.